# How to check if an XML node exists in the children of another node?

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlnode

I want to add an `XmlNode` to another `XmlNode` if it doesn't contain this node (the comparison should be based on the node name and its contents)

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc;
...
XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateElement(name);
newNode.InnerXml = something
XmlNode parentNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName(parentName);
if (parentNode.???? (newNode))
{
    parentNode.AppendChild(newNode);
}
```

How can I check this existence? `parentNode.ChildNodes` doesn't have a `Contain` method.

Comment: [XmlNode.ChildNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)[.Contains(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Is `XmlDocument` a requirement here?  LINQ to XML would make this simpler as it's a nicer API and happens to have a `DeepEquals` method for comparison of nodes.

Comment: @Jashaszun it doesn't have a contain method

Comment: @CharlesMager I need a class like `System.Xml.XmlDocument` if you know another class I can use it too

Comment: @CharlesMager where is it? I can't find such a class, or a reference which contains it, my IDE doesn't have `System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: LINQ to XML is part of .NET 3.5 and later.  What version of .NET are you targeting?  Ensure you add a reference to `System.Xml` and `System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: @CharlesMager .Net 4.5!!!

Comment: Then it's there.  Add a reference to it and ensure you have the appropriate `using` statements.

Comment: @CharlesMager the reference contains `System.Xml`, it is in using too, but there is no `Linq`

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the trick:

```
    private void doSomething() 
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateElement("name");
        newNode.InnerXml = "something";
        XmlNode parentNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("parentName")[0]; 
            // I just stuck an index on end of above line... 
            // Note that GetElementsByTagName returns an XmlNodeList

        int huh = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode n in parentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            // If I understood you correctly, you want these checks?
            if (n.InnerXml == newNode.InnerXml && n.Name == newNode.Name) huh++;
        }

        if (huh == 0) parentNode.AppendChild(newNode);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using LINQ to XML making use of the `XNode.DeepEquals` method to compare your child nodes for equality.  An example might look like this - the `duplicateChild` will not be added but `newChild` will be:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("parent",
        new XElement("child", 1)));

var parent = doc.Descendants("parent").Single();

var duplicateChild = new XElement("child", 1);
var newChild = new XElement("child", 2);

if (!parent.Elements().Any(e => XNode.DeepEquals(e, duplicateChild)))
{
    parent.Add(duplicateChild);
}

if (!parent.Elements().Any(e => XNode.DeepEquals(e, newChild)))
{
    parent.Add(newChild);
}
```

A demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1t4Q1b